# jquery swapping image on div rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to achieve a simple swapping effect on div rollover but its not working.

Here is the HTML

```
<li><div id="main1"><a href="#"><img src="images/plane1.jpg" id="image1" style="margin:0 4px; margin-left:0;"/></a>
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h3>Hollywood</h3>
                </div></div>
            </li>
```

and jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('#main1').hover (function () {
    $('#image1').src="images/img01.jpg";
    }, function () {
    $('#image1').src="images/plane1.jpg";

    });});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[PURE CSS demo 1](http://jsbin.com/zaqow/2/edit)**       **[PURE CSS demo 2 (With fade fx)](http://jsbin.com/zaqow/3/edit)**
A better way? **Without JS.**  *Why?*
Cause **if you use JS**, on hover you need to wait for a new server request for the new image so... by doing it this way you'll have a quite professional result.

```
<li>
  <div id="main1">
    <a href="#">
       <img src="images/plane1.jpg"/>
       <img src="images/img01.jpg"/> <!-- this one is hidden but loaded! -->
    </a>
    <div class="flex-caption">
      <h3>Hollywood</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#main1 > a       img+img{ display:none;  }
#main1 > a:hover img+img{ display:block; }
```

---

If you're just learning jQuery, JS in general and you want to play:

```
var $img = $('#image'); // Cache the elements you plan to reuse!
$('#main1').hover(function() {
    $img[0].src = "images/img01.jpg";
}, function () {
    $img[0].src = "images/plane1.jpg";
});
```

Or also using an array:

```
var arr = ["images/plane1.jpg", "images/img01.jpg"];
var $img = $('#image');
$('#main1').hover(function() {
    $img[0].src = arr.reverse()[0];
});
```

Or also using the *Conditional Operator `?:`* (AKA *Ternary Operator*):

```
var $img = $('#image');
$('#main1').hover(function( ev ) {
   $img[0].src = "images/"+ (ev.type=="mouseenter"?"img01":"plane1") +".jpg"; 
});
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't work as needed, i want to hide first image on rollover and show only on rollout. yes, server problem is bad but i am loading them first and keeping them invisible.

Comment: @stacksam I cannot believe I'm telling this but: *than just swap images order in HTML untill you get the needed result* :) that simple?!

Comment: Thanks Roko , infact i got bunch of images for this effect, as the results i got alot of functions to do the same thing. i will try array and see if i could solve this problem , thanks alot

Comment: again , array also didn't work! maybe if html and css work then i will stick to it.

Comment: great, html method work and i prefer this than jquery but the only problem that i see if i hover through the <div class="flex-caption">
      <h3>Hollywood</h3>
    </div> it doesn't work ..

Comment: Roko , i was able to get the same functionality with your procedure with html/css , it works well , the only problem that i see i am now restricted to a predefined height!

Comment: can't thank you enough for this, you saved me from 100 lines for my entire page and left me down to 4 lines only through css..

Comment: @stacksam no, you don't have to use fixed heights... http://jsbin.com/zaqow/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method instead of .src. Something like:

```
$('#image1').attr('src', 'images/img01.jpg')
```

Comment: @stacksam it would work with javascript's `.src` but than you need to return the `this` pointer from the jQuery Object like: `$('#image1')[0].src`